# Uncaught TypeError: No matching signature

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that will console.log the URL from the chrome tab.

I keep on getting this error: *Uncaught TypeError: No matching signature.*

Please can someone tell me how to fix this?

**Background.js:**

```
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
            let ff = tabs[0].url;
            console.log(ff)
            }      
        ); 
    }
)
```

**Manifest.json:**

```
        "name": "Project Name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "webRequest", 
        "http://*/*/*",
        "https://*/*/*",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Thank You!